# If $a^2+b^2 = c^2 + \sqrt{3}$, find value of $\angle C$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> In a triangle with sides $a$, $b$, $c$, consider this relationship: 
>   $$a^2+b^2 = c^2 +\sqrt 3$$
>   Now find value of $\measuredangle C$ .

My try: I tried to use Laws of Cosines and Law of Sinee, but I didn't get any result.

Comment: @Samjoe I know that $C$ angle is eaqual to 60 degree

Comment: You mean $60°$ is the answer to be found ?

Comment: $a^2+b^2 = c^2 +\sqrt 3$ and $a^2+b^2-2ab \cos \hat C=c^2$ (law of cosines) gives you, by subtraction $ab \cos \hat C=\sqrt{3}/2$. But after that...

Comment: @JeanMarie Yea i did same.. and then put it in terms of c. We have to show $ab = \sqrt{3}$

Comment: You need more information to determine a triangle, $3$ in fact. $2$ sides and $1$ angle, or $3$ sides, or $3$ angles, or $2$ angles and $1$ side.

Comment: Yes , in the answer said that.

Comment: @zwin I think that this is special case .

Comment: are you sure that there isn't a typo?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes , I'm sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that can really be concluded about $\angle C$ is, as others have said, that $$\cos(C) = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2ab} \tag{1}$$ 
and, as others have **not** said, that $$\angle C \lt 90^\circ \tag{2}$$

We can conclude statement $2$ by seeing that the right hand side of equation $1$ is always positive. And the cosine function is only positive for angles in the intervals $0^\circ \le \angle C \lt 90^\circ$ and $270^\circ \lt \angle C \le 360^\circ$. As no angle in a triangle is greater than $180^\circ$, the conclusion follows.

Comment: So , there are infinite solutions for angle $C$ . Is it right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Using an acute angle leads to $a^2 + b^2 + (some value) = c^2$ which is not the same as $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + (some value)$.For the square on the hypothenuse to be greater than what is obtained by the Pythagorean theorem (in this case by $\sqrt 3$), the angle must be obtuse (longer hypothenuse).  The problem statement clearly indicates that $a & b$ remain constant and that it is the right hand side, that is the area on the hypothenuse, that must be greater than what is obtained from Pythagoras.  Subtracting Pythagoras from the law of cosines yields $-2ab cos(C) = \sqrt 3$.

Comment: @MathAddict I think you are being confused by the similarity of the equation with Pythagoras. Just view the equation as one giving a relation between the sides of the triangle, like $a^2+b^2=2c$ or $a^2+2b= c$ or something else. Then go from there.

Comment: In your solution, you are making $c^2$ smaller by $\sqrt 3$.  The problem statement does not change $c^2$, it simply asks for the **angle** (the variable) which will cause the resulting square to be the original $c^2$ plus $\sqrt 3$.  Think of it this way, if you were fencing some land and you have 2 sticks of length a and b to figure out the $c^2$ area to fence and, you want to fence an area that is $c^2 + \sqrt 3$, the angle between the sticks a and b must be obtuse, not acute.  With an acute angle, you'd end up fencing a smaller area, $c^2 - \sqrt 3$ instead of $c^2 + \sqrt 3$.

Comment: @MathAddict I am not making $c^2$ smaller by $\sqrt 3$. The side $c$ has the length $c$. No side of the triangle has the length $\sqrt{c^2+\sqrt 3}$. Just use the equation as given, combine it with the Cosine law and you get the above result. There is no interpretation. I'm not sure I can make this any clearer.

Comment: Clearer, that seems to be the key.  The Pythagorean theorem is just a specific case of the Law of Cosines, specifically when the angle is 90 degrees.  That means the problem presented here is, $a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\ cos(C = 90) = c^2$ where the angle C has to change (from 90 to something else) in such a way that the result is $a^2 + b^2 -2ab\ cos(C) = c^2 + \sqrt 3$.  Since $c^2 + \sqrt 3$ is greater than just $c^2$, then the angle must be obtuse, not acute.  Like you, I don't know how to make it clearer than that.

Answer (score 2):

Applying the comments mentioned, we have $ab \cos \measuredangle C = \dfrac {\sqrt 3}{2}$.

Let us consider the special case for a = b = 1 first. We build the red-dotted unit circle centered at C with radius = CB = CA = 1. Then $\measuredangle C = … = 30^0$.

[image]

If we don’t like the above isosceles triangle solution, we can build another one, which is A’B’C (the green triangle). See below.

We assume that $\alpha = A’C \lt B’C = \beta$. (To avoid confusion, I let the legs of angle C be $\alpha$ and $\beta$.)

We construct the black circle (centered at C with radius $ = \alpha$. Locate A’’ on CB. We further located B’, which is the inversion point of A’’ about the red-dotted circle such that $\alpha \times \beta = 1$. Or equivalently, $A’’B’ = \beta - \alpha$.

By varying A’, we can obtain infinitely many triangles meeting the requirement. Another infinite set of solution can be obtained if we let $\beta \lt \alpha$. However, I cannot exhaust other possibilities that $\angle C =$ an angle with other sizes.

Comment: Okay but can you prove that there are infinitely value for $\angle C$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W No. Actually, your question is asking for the "***value*** of C".

Comment: Okay but your question is not mentioned that only possible value of $\angle C$ is 30.

Comment: @S.H.W I found that C = 30 is one of the possible solutions. Associated with it, there are infinitely variants. I have also mentioned that there are other possibilities. In fact, if, neither a nor b were specifically given, it is not possible to exhaust them all.  $C = 30^0$ will do the job because your question is to "find value of $\angle C$" (in singular).

Answer (score 1):

Note: In what follows I am interpreting $a^2+b^2 = c^2 +\sqrt 3$ as meaning that $c^2$ is larger than what would be obtained using the Pythagorean theorem by $\sqrt 3$.

Since you must have $$a^2+b^2 = c^2 +\sqrt 3$$ the law of cosines states that in this case $$- 2\ a\ b\ cos (\measuredangle C) = \sqrt 3$$ Therefore the angle is determined by the formula $$\measuredangle C = \arccos(-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2\ a\ b})$$.

**Note:** if the interpretation should have been that $a^2 + b^2$ is smaller than $c^2$ (as obtained using the Pythagorean theorem) by $\sqrt 3$ then the above equation is the same but without the minus sign.

$\measuredangle C$ varies with the values of $a$ and $b$ therefore there are an infinite number of values for $\measuredangle C$.  For example, in the figure below (showing both possible interpretations)

[image]

when $a$ and $b$ are both 1, then $\measuredangle C$ is $150 ^{\circ}$.  When $a$ and $b$ are both $2$, then $\measuredangle C$ is $102.5^{\circ}$.  In both cases $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + \sqrt 3$ as required.  Given any values of $a$ and $b$, the value of $\measuredangle C$ can be calculated to make $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + \sqrt 3 $.

Comment: In your second equation, there shouldn't be a minus sign.

Comment: I interpreted the OP's question as wanting $c^2$ to be greater by $\sqrt 3$ than what is obtained using the Pythagorean theorem.  If my interpretation is correct then the second equation is correct.  On the other hand, if what is meant is for $c^2$ to be smaller by $\sqrt 3$ than what is obtained by the Pythagorean theorem then, you are correct and the minus sign shouldn't be there.

Comment: If $a=b=1$, $c\leq1$ obviously. So・・・.

Comment: not obviously, because it depends on the angle.  If acute then less, if right then equal and if obtuse then greater.  It is quite obvious in the figure.

Answer (score 1):

We have by simple triangle trigonometry

$$ a\,b \cos C= \sqrt 3/2 $$

which is the scalar dot product of vector forces $ (A,B)$ with angle  $C$ included between them, This fixed/given amount of mechanical work can be performed in infinitely many ways with variabilities among the three available degrees of freedom, one for each parameter $a,b,C.$  It can have no unique solution to determine angle $C$ .. as required by the question. Often the underlying physics can be exploited to gain clarity.