# Determine type of triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

We know that $ABC$ is a triangle and also $\sin3A + \cos4B = 2$ . Now determine type of tringle . (Equilateral triangle , Isosceles , right triangle , ....)

Comment: HINT:$$\sin x,\cos x\le1$$ for real $x$

Comment: One hint, and done! nice hint there!

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Very good answer , Thank you . Can you see this question too : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2171249/find-value-of-angle-c?noredirect=1#comment4465777_2171249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$max(\sin 3A)=1\\max(\cos 4B)=1 \\\sin 3A+\cos 4B=1+1 \to \\simultaniusly \\
\begin{cases}\sin 3A=1  & A\leq\pi  \to 3A\leq 3\pi \\cos 4B=1 & B\leq \pi \to 4B\leq 4\pi\end{cases} $$
$$\begin{cases}\sin 3A=1  & 3A= \dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{5\pi}{2} \\cos 4B=1 &  4B=0,2\pi,4\pi\end{cases}$$ in second one $4B=0,4\pi$ are not acceptable because $A+B+C=180 \to B\neq0 ,180^0$ so $4B=2\pi \to B=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$
$$\hat B=90 \to
 \begin{cases} 3A= \dfrac{\pi}{2}=90 \to \hat A=30 \to \hat C=60 \\3A= \dfrac{5\pi}{2}\to A=150 \to A+B+C=90+150+C =180 (no-solution)\end{cases}$$

Comment: If you hold down *Alt*, type 0176 on your numeric keypad, then release *Alt*, you will get the degree symbol ° which will allow you to improve your post.

Comment: @Joffan:thank about your useful hint